# replace NA in multiple columns of different classes

Tags: r, class, dplyr, tidyr, na

I have data with multiple columns of similar names, but of different classes. I need to replace all `NA` with `0` but retain the columns class, as different character strings will be assigned other numeric values later.

This is example data:

```
qdf = data.frame(bicep_wt = c("black band", "5", NA),
                 tricep_wt = c(2,NA,3))
```

and this is my attempt to change the NA to 0:

```
mutate(qdf, across(contains("wt"), ~case_when(is.numeric(.x) ~ tidyr::replace_na(., 0),
                                              is.character(.x) ~ tidyr::replace_na(., "0"))))
```

I get error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `bicep_wt`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the right-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `vec_assign()`:
! Can't convert `replace` <double> to match type of `data` <character>.
```

same error with:

```
mutate(qdf, across(contains("wt"), ~case_when(is.numeric(.x) ~ tidyr::replace_na(.x, 0),
                                              is.character(.x) ~ tidyr::replace_na(.x, "0"))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While being "class-safe" is usually a good thing, functions that are not class-safe can be used advantageously.

```r
mutate(qdf, across(contains("wt"), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), 0)))
#     bicep_wt tricep_wt
# 1 black band         2
# 2          5         0
# 3          0         3
```

By "class-safe", I mean that you are guaranteed of the class returns from an expression. For instance,

```r
ifelse(c(T, T), 1, "1")
# [1] 1 1
ifelse(c(T, F), 1, "1")
# [1] "1" "1"
```

The first call is ambiguous, since the `yes=` is class numeric and the `no=` is class character. A class-safe function should complain about this, as in

```r
dplyr::if_else(c(T, T), 1, "1")
# Error in dplyr::if_else(c(T, T), 1, "1") : 
#   Can't combine `true` <double> and `false` <character>.
data.table::fifelse(c(T, T), 1, "1")
# Error in data.table::fifelse(c(T, T), 1, "1") : 
#   'yes' is of type double but 'no' is of type character. Please make sure that both arguments have the same type.
```

Note that `ifelse` and `replace` are *not* class-safe, but in this case it is acceptable based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the condition to inside `replace_na`:

```
mutate(qdf, across(contains("wt"), ~ replace_na(.x, `if`(is.numeric(.x), 0, "0"))))
```

Result:

```
    bicep_wt tricep_wt
1 black band         2
2          5         0
3          0         3
```

Obs: it works with either `ifelse()` or `` `if`() ``.

Answer (score 0):

```
mutate(
  qdf, 
  across(
    contains("wt"), 
    \(.x) { # could use ~ instead
      if      (is.numeric(.x)  ) tidyr::replace_na(.x, 0)
      else if (is.character(.x)) tidyr::replace_na(.x, "0")
    }
  )
)


#     bicep_wt tricep_wt
# 1 black band         2
# 2          5         0
# 3          0         3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know that your columns will be only numeric or character, you can do a version that will substitute the correct type of NA no matter what.

**1) With a loop**

```
for (col in colnames(qdf)) {
  qdf[is.na(qdf[, col]), col] <- 0
}
```

**2) With a function and `lapply()`**

```
naToZero <- function(v) {
  v[is.na(v)] <- 0
  return(v)
}
qdf <- data.frame(lapply(X=qdf, FUN=function(u) naToZero(u)))
qdf
    bicep_wt tricep_wt
1 black band         2
2          5         0
3          0         3
```